# What is the difference between a symbol and its name?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

In *The Scheme Programming Language*,

> the Scheme reader (invoked by get-datum and read) and the procedure
>   string->symbol catalog symbols in **an internal symbol table** and always return the same **symbol**
>   whenever the same **name** is encountered.

What are the keys and values in the "**internal symbol table**"?

Does "always return the same **symbol** whenever the same **name** is encountered" imply that a symbol and its name are two different concepts?

What do `string->symbol` and `symbol->string`  distinguish a symbol from? Do they distinguish a symbol from its name (as a string)?

The same book says

> Keywords, variables, and **symbols** are collectively called **identifiers**.

Are an identifier and a name  the same concept? If yes, what is the difference between a symbol and its name?

Comment: key = string -> value = symbol

Answer (score 3):

Symbols are, at the simplest level, *names with identity*.  That's what you want in any programming language for identifiers: if, when the compiler is looking at some code, it sees some variable name `foo` it needs to know that it is *the same variable* as some other name `foo` elsewhere in the program (subject to the scope & extent rules of the language of course).  Implementationally this means that that symbols get *interned* into some kind of table so that you can answer questions like 'is this thing the same as that thing?' and 'have I already seen this thing?' very quickly.  In particular at the point where you have a sequence of characters which you've decided is going to be the name of a symbol, then you look up that name in the table, and if it's there you use the existing symbol, while if it's not you make a new symbol, store it in the table, and return that.

Large numbers of programming language *implementations* use some kind of symbol structure and one or more symbol tables (the process of linking is substantially the process of establishing that pairs of symbols are in fact the same symbol for instance, so things in libraries (named by symbols) can get associated with references to them (named by symbols).

But programming languages *which want to talk about programming languages* often expose symbols as objects at the language level, because this is just obviously useful.  Lisp and Scheme (or 'Lisp-family languages' or however you want to divide things up) are one of the canonical examples of programming languages which are about programming languages.

I am not as familiar with Scheme standards as I should be (I'm a Racket & CL person), but:

- `string->symbol` takes a string and returns a possibly-newly-constructed symbol with that name, which is *interned*, returning an identical symbol each time it is called with a string with the same sequence of characters;
- `symbol->string` takes a symbol and tells you its name, which is a string.

So in particular it is the case that

```
(eq? (string->symbol "foo") (string->symbol "foo"))
```

is true.  And even more strongly

```
(eq? (string->symbol (make-string 3 #\f))
     (string->symbol (make-string 3 #\f)))
```

is true.  However

```
(eq? (make-string 3 #\f)
     (make-string 3 #\f))
```

is *false*, because `make-string` makes a new string, which is not `eq?` to any other string (or any other object), since it is new.

So `string->symbol` is the thing you would call if you were implementing a language at the point where you had a sequence of characters which you wanted to name a symbol.

`symbol->string` is how you get the name of a symbol: it's what you'd call if you wanted to print it.  It's typically not defined (and I think actually not defined) whether

```
(let ((s (string->symbol "s")))
  (eq? (symbol->string s)
       (symbol->string s)))
```

is true or false: it may be that `symbol->string` returns the string that actually *is* the name of the symbol, or it may return a copy of it (and there's no requirement for the 'string which actually is the name' to actually exist anywhere: for instance the table where symbols live could be a trie which does not store the strings which name them anywhere.

It will be the case that

```
(let ((s (string->symbol "s")))
  (string=? (symbol->string s)
            (symbol->string s)))
```

is true however.

So to answer your question: yes, a symbol and its name are different concepts, and the difference is this notion of *identity*: if you have two symbols you can know if they are in fact the same symbol by comparing them with `eq?`, while if you have two *names* (strings) you need to compare them element-wise.

---

I think that this is as far as Scheme goes (at least it's as far as R5RS & R6RS go I think).  However there are two generalisations to this notion of symbol which are important.

**Uninterned symbols.**  Above I've described symbols as being interned in some kind of table whose keys are the strings which name symbols.  But there's another possibility: you could create a symbol, but then stop before actually interning it in the table.  The result is a symbol which has a name but that name is unutterable.  An uninterned symbol breaks the equivalence between names and symbols.  In particular, for *interned* symbols it is always the case that, if `(string=? (symbol->string x) (symbol->string y))` then `(eq? x y)`, but *this is not true* if one or both `x` or `y` are not interned.

This sounds like a useless thing to be able to do, but it's not.

A program may want to create a symbol which it is absolutely certain does not already exist.  If there were only interned symbols then it has to do this by creating a new name, each time, and then checking that *no symbol with that name exists*.  The two procedures I've described above *aren't enough to do even this*, because once you've called `string->symbol` then the symbol *does* exist: you'd need an additional `string-names-symbol?` predicate which checked if a symbol named by its argument existed but did not create it if it did not (and then in a multithreaded implementation you would need some atomicity around everything which would make things even more complicated).

Well, one solution to that is just to create an uninterned symbol: this is a symbol which you can be absolutely certain does not already exist, because its name is unutterable.

But, well, *why* would a program want a symbol which it is absolutely sure does not already exist?  The traditional answer to this is *macros*: programs which write programs.  Let's say you are writing some macro which is at some point going to want to create some code like this:

```
(let ((my-variable ...))
  ... do something with my-variable ...
  ... some code I don't control is in here ...
  ... do something else with my-variable ...)
```

Well, there's a problem here: what if the code you don't control includes the use of a variable named `my-variable`: oops.  But if I arrange life so that the variable I bind is a brand new symbol with an unutterable name, then I *know* that the code I don't control can't talk about it, simply because it can't ever utter its name to get hold of it.  Well, that's what uninterned symbols do.

Here is an example CL macro which uses this trick:

```
(defmacro p1 (form &body forms)
  (let ((stashn (make-symbol "STASH")))
    `(let ((,stashn ,form))
       ,@forms
       ,stashn)))
```

This uses the CL `make-symbol` function to make a new, uninterned symbol, and then uses it to capture the value of the first subform, before evaluating the remaining subforms & then returning the value it stashed.

A form like this

```
(p1 1
  2
  3)
```

Expands to this

```
(let ((#:stash 1))
  2
  3
  #:stash)
```

Where `#:` is the notation CL uses for uninterned symbols.  Note that CL can create uninterned symbols in the reader using this notation, but, for instance

```
> (eq '#:foo '#:foo)
nil
```

However the two symbols in the macroexpansion above are in fact the same symbol, and you can persuade the printer to show you they are:

```
> (let ((*print-circle* t))
    (pprint (macroexpand '(p1 1 2 3))))

(let ((#1=#:stash 1)) 2 3 #1#)
```

The `#1=` & `#1#` notation tells you that the two things are the same thing.  And yes, you can use this at read-time too:

```
> (eq '#1=#:foo '#1#)
t
```

Scheme has adopted a different approach to solving this problem (and this is probably why R5RS & R6RS don't provide facilities to deal with uninterned symbols), but this approach is how you deal with it in Lisps like Common Lisp, for instance.

(Note that uninterned symbols give the lie to my claim that a symbol doesn't need to know its name: uninterned symbols really do (although I could imagine an implementation where uninterned symbols simply had no name, so, well, I don't know).)

**Richer symbols.**  Once you have symbols you can hang all sorts of things from them, and this has traditionally been done.  For instance, symbols in Common Lisp are conceptually very rich objects, having:

- variable values via `symbol-value` (this is distinct from their use to name lexically-bound variables in code);
- function-values via `symbol-function`;
- property lists via `symbol-plist`;
- and also being used to name things like classes and so on.

CL also makes the tables where symbols get interned first-class objects – packages – so you can do a lot of introspection about what symbols exist and so on.

One way to think about doing things like this is that symbols become big objects: symbols actually have slots for the various things that belong to them.  But this does not have to be the case: here is a bit of Racket code which gives symbols an additional `funge` slot:

```
#lang racket

(define funges (make-hasheq))

(define (symbol-funge? s)
  (hash-has-key? funges s))

(define (symbol-funge s (default (thunk
                                  (error "no funge"))))
  (hash-ref funges s default))

(define (set-symbol-funge! s v)
  (hash-set! funges s v))

(define (remove-symbol-funge! s)
  (hash-remove! funges s))
```

So, even in CL, all the additional 'slots' in symbols don't actually need to exist in the symbols themselves.

---

Note: languages which want to talk about languages, and have symbols to help them do so may or may not use the same mechanisms to talk about *themselves* as to talk about other languages that are being built *in* the language.  Traditionally Lisps used symbols explicitly in their own implementations a lot, but that is less the case now than it was.

Scheme, I think, needs no use of symbols in its own description at all other than as objects which are implemented in the language: the specification talks about 'identifiers' (see the comment to this article by Chris Vine), and the macro system does not rely on symbols.

CL is much more traditional and symbols play a bigger role in the description of the language.  In particular CL's macro system explicitly involves manipulating the source of programs represented as structures involving symbols which name things: this is why CL needs uninterned symbols to create unique names.

However even in the CL case symbols can fade into the background in the implementation.  Consider this CL function definition:

```
(defun sum-tree (tree)
  (labels ((summit (branch sum)
             (etypecase branch
               (null sum)
               (number (+ sum branch))
               (cons
                (summit (car branch) (summit (cdr branch) sum))))))
    (summit tree 0)))
```

If I type this interactively at a fresh CL REPL (in a package which only uses the `CL` package) then five new symbols will be created: `sum-tree`, `tree`, `summit`, `branch`, & `sum`, and one of those symbols, `sum-tree` will name a function, so `(fboundp sum-tree)` will be true and `(fdefinition 'sum-tree)` will return a function.

If I then compile this definition with `(compile 'sum-tree)`, those symbols will still all exist.

But if I put this definition in a file and (each time in a fresh CL):

- compile & load the file with `(compile-file ... :load t)`;
- or compile the file with `(compile-file ...)`, *start a new CL* and then load the file with `(load ...)`.

Then what symbols are created?  In each case `sum-tree` is created and bound to a function, but it's not at all clear what other symbols are created.  In the days of `comp.lang.lisp` I'm sure people had heated arguments about what `compile-file` needs to do: is it *required* to use `read` (yes I think it is) and if so is it allowed to unwind side-effects of `read` and if so which ones?  Can it unintern symbols that `read` interned?  In the final case where the compile file is loaded in a completely fresh instance I think it's very clear that the only symbol that needs to be created is `sum-tree`.

Similarly in CL, unlike in some very old implementations, it's not the case that in a form like

```
(let ((x ...)) ...)
```

I can, in the body, expect to use some introspection on the symbol `x` at run-time to find what value it is bound to (it may be possible at macro-expansion time to work out which symbols will be bound at runtime, although it it not portably so in CL).

Comment: Scheme speaks of 'identifiers' rather than of binding an interned symbol to a value - see §2.1 of R7RS. In scheme, an 'identifier' is just a name.  An identifier name is treated as identifying a variable unless it identifies a macro (syntax) or it is in a context requiring it to be treated as identifying a symbol, such as by quotation. In particular, §2.1 of R7RS states that "When an identifier appears as a literal or within a literal (see section 4.1.2), it is being used to denote a symbol (see section 6.5)".  Unlike CL, scheme avoids mixing the implementation with the specification.

Comment: @ChrisVine: yes, other than in the macro case (with a note that Scheme does not do this) I've explicitly avoided talking about symbols-as-variable-names *in the native language itself*: Scheme needs symbols so it can talk about languages, but those languages are not Scheme (or, they may be, but they're different Scheme's than the Scheme being used to do the talking...).

Comment: @ChrisVine: I've added a big note on whether Lisps use symbols in their own description & implementation: would welcome corrections to it: the CL stuff is right I think, the Scheme stuff may be less so.

Comment: All I meant is that in scheme symbols are not necessarily the means by which names are given identity, as in the case of CL. "Identifiers" are what have identity.  However, interning a symbol is a perfectly good scheme implementation of identifiers, and probably the way most schemes do it: they are suitable for that use because symbols are just things which have the properties mentioned in §6.5 of R7RS (§11.10 of R6RS).

Comment: @ChrisVine: that's what I was trying to get at in my note at the end: Schemes may or may not use symbols in their own implementation, because everything is defined in terms of identifiers, so they could not.  But when being used to reason about *other* languages (excluding languages defined by macros on top of Scheme) they need to use symbols because identifiers don't really exist as first-class objects in the language.  (At least I think that's correct.)

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp, a symbol is a value made of:

- a name, which is a string
- an optional package
- (additional properties, not relevant here)

If the symbol has no package, it is said to be *uninterned*.
For example, this makes an uninterned symbol:

```
CL-USER> (make-symbol "SOME-NAME")
#:SOME-NAME
```

Two symbols are identical if they have the same name and the same *non-nil* package. Two uninterned symbols are never equal:

```
CL-USER> (eq (make-symbol "A") (make-symbol "A"))
NIL
```

When you [`INTERN`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) a symbol in a package, it is registered in that package, and further invocation of `intern` with the same name and package gives you the *same* symbol:

```
CL-USER> (eq (intern "A" "CL-USER") (intern "A" "CL-USER"))
T
```

Basically, symbols are a way to cache identifiers.

You generally do not call `intern` directly, this is done automatically by the Lisp reader. That means that one a form is *read*, all symbols are resolved to the appropriate underlying symbols, and no name lookup occurs at runtime (you don't compare names, which are strings, but compare symbols by their identity).